# ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS noetic for ubuntu 20.04 following the steps presented on the next page: http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu, but the rqt command is not working for me and it always shows the following error

```
-->rqt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/rqt", line 13, in
sys.exit(main.main())
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 61, in main
return super(
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 407, in main
from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/init.py", line 55, in
from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION # @UnusedImport
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 274, in
_select_qt_binding(
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 108, in _select_qt_binding
QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 155, in _load_pyqt
_named_optional_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 142, in _named_optional_import
_named_import(name)
File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 133, in _named_import
module = builtins.import(name)
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371691/valueerror:-pycapsule_getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name/) by [anonymous69844](https://answers.ros.org/users/69844/anonymous69844/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

problem solved by uninstalling PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip with pip3

---

Originally posted by [anonymous69844](https://answers.ros.org/users/69844/anonymous69844/) with karma: 26 on 2021-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EPisano](https://answers.ros.org/users/72362/episano/) on 2021-03-26**:
thanks, It solved also my problem

**Comment by [gorkemsavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/86433/gorkemsavran/) on 2021-10-06**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-12-30**:
I'm curious how this happened. Perhaps you had previously installed PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip with pip3, and then the instructions installed an older version PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip via apt. If this is the case, it might make sense to improve the Noetic install instructions somehow.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-12-30**:
Can the Noetic install instructions be improved?

**Comment by [bruttherjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/109927/bruttherjoe/) on 2023-08-02**:
Thank you, this solved my problem too.

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
pip3 uninstall PyQt5-sip
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all,

great! It should be added that "apt remove python3-pyqt5" does not do the trick. When I do this, it would remove the whole ros installation.

Thanks!
Werner

---

Originally posted by [TheWerner](https://answers.ros.org/users/73668/thewerner/) with karma: 31 on 2021-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3